# Access localhost and docker network using docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have two different services running in a single docker-compose file. I talk to each service by referring to the service name of the containers.

Now I want my container A to access localhost as well. For this when I added the configuration of 'network_mode=host', but this creates an error now stating that container A cannot talk to container B.

```
version: '2'

services:
  rocketchat:
    image: myimage
    environment:
      - MONGO_URL=mongodb://mongo:27017/dbname
    depends_on:
      - mongo
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    network_mode: host

  mongo:
    image: mongo:3.2
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
```

For each compose file docker-compose creates a network so in this case, should I manually assign the containers to a dedicated network as well? Or is there any workaround to access both the networks?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

try to add `links` :

```
version: '2'

services:
  rocketchat:
    image: myimage
    environment:
      - MONGO_URL=mongodb://mongo:27017/dbname
    depends_on:
      - mongo
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    links:
      - mongo
    #network_mode: host

  mongo:
    image: mongo:3.2
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
```

and you do not need `network_mode: host` if you use the links

**EDIT - Other solution:**

```
version: '2'

services:
  rocketchat:
    image: myimage
    environment:
      - MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost:27017/dbname
    depends_on:
      - mongo
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    network_mode: host

  mongo:
    image: mongo:3.2
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    network_mode: host
```